# How does GPRS icon look like in iOS 11? (screenshot)

Tags: iphone, ios, network, cellular-data

How does GPRS icon look like on iPhone with iOS 11? I would like to see some screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the GPRS icon (and the other status icons and symbols) from iOS 11 here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207354

The GPRS icon is not a graphic icon, but rather the text "GPRS" in a specific font.